# Why am I getting error after looping into file and trying to join the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, tkinter

I have large text file which has numbers. I want to loop through the file and append the numbers to the list_of_numbers. Problem is that the loop appends to the list but not in the way I want, that's why the list looks like this after iteration

```
['\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '8', '5', '0', '7', '7', '6', '4', '\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '7', '6', '4', '6', '0', '2', '9', '\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '7', '6', '4', '6', '8', '4', '6', '\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '8', '5', '0', '5', '9', '3', '4', '\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '7', '6', '4', '0', '7', '8', '3', '\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '7', '6', '4', '9', '2', '8', '2', '\n', '+', '1', '6', '1', '0', '7', '6', '4', '0', '0', '4', '9', '\n']
```

this is just part of the output. I want this to be in this type [123455334,492023232,32322323]

I tried to do this but it does not work and gets errors

```
print(list([int(x) for x in ''.join(list_of_numbers).split('\n')]))
```

here is my full code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver


list_of_numbers=[]
full_list_of_numbers=[]

def openFile():
    tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="C:/Users/MainFrame/Desktop/",
        title="Open Text file",
        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
        )
    pathh.insert(END, tf)
    tf = open(tf)  # or tf = open(tf, 'r')
    data = tf.read()
    txtarea.insert(END, data)
    tf.close()
    for i in data:
        list_of_numbers.append(i)



print(list_of_numbers)


ws = Tk()
ws.title("PythonGuides")
ws.geometry("400x450")
ws['bg']='#fb0'

txtarea = Text(ws, width=40, height=20)
txtarea.pack(pady=20)

pathh = Entry(ws)
pathh.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=X, padx=20)



Button(
    ws,
    text="Open File",
    command=openFile
    ).pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill=X, padx=20)


ws.mainloop()

print(list_of_numbers)


while ' ' in list_of_numbers:
    list_of_numbers.remove(' ')

print(list([int(x) for x in ''.join(list_of_numbers).split('\n')]))
```

Comment: Can you please show us the full error traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at that part

```
tf = open(tf)  # or tf = open(tf, 'r')
data = tf.read()
txtarea.insert(END, data)
tf.close()
for i in data:
    list_of_numbers.append(i)
```

`data` is one big string. Then you iterate over it one char at a time and append that single char (incl, `'+'` and `'\n'` to the list. So you get what you get.

Replace the above snippet with following:

```
with open(tf) as f: # use context manager
    for line in f:
        txtarea.insert(END, line)
        list_of_numbers.append(int(line))
```

Note, this assumes there are no empty lines in your file. If there are, then

```
with open(tf) as f: # use context manager
    for line in f:
        txtarea.insert(END, line)
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            list_of_numbers.append(int(line))
```

Comment: i did not understand i tried this   Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/sachi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/lool.py", line 24, in openFile
    with open(tf) as f:  # use context manager
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: Hm. in the snippet, you use `filedialog.askopenfilename`. This will return `str`. The traceback claims `tf` is `_io.TextIOWraper`. That will be the case if you use `filedialog.askopenfile`. Did you make that change? Or did you keep `tf = open(tf)`? If you did - remove it.

Comment: i kept tf= open(tf) , but what have to do so the code works can you add the edited code to comment?

Comment: Don't get it. - replace your code (that I reference in my answer) with my code.

Comment: Did you read my note about empty lines and check my second snippet?

Comment: yeah i did , now code is working , just confused bcs i wanted + sign into the number example +1998897879  but its just showing the number withouth + sign

Comment: Well, you desired output is `[123455334,492023232,32322323]`, i.e. these are `int`, not `str`, like `['+123455334', '+492023232', '+32322323']`. And in your failed attempt you try to convert to `int` too. If you want the `'+'` you have to keep them as `str` - remove the conversion to `int`